# What is the best practice for sharing routes between multiple Vue applications?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Our team has been developing large web project which includes multiple applications. 
All is written by **vuejs** using **vue-router**.

Sometimes we need to jump between the applications.

Currently, in all apps there is `routes.js` file, where list of all routes stored.
if we add new route in vue-router, `routes.js` should be updated in all apps.

It doesnt seem like good way.

Any solution would be appreciated!

Comment: The VueJS projects are totally separated?

Comment: Not using vue, so it might not help, you can pass any kind of infos between tabs or workers with the native BroadcastChannel api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel
That works with subdomains.

Comment: @DimitriusLachi Yes right, hosts are same and share the same cookies, but subdomains are different

Comment: @Cryptopat This is good too, but IE support :(

Comment: :/ 30 versions of firefox later, still not in ie! Looks like «polyfills» is doable: https://github.com/pubkey/broadcast-channel Otherwise the similar postMessage api is working since ie8

Comment: @Cryptopat thanks again. Ive checked the repo, it is very useful, but only for the same origin

Comment: Maybe isolate the routes.js file and import as git submodule in the projects

Comment: @OliCrt we also tried this, but it is not comfortable to push/pull in every change